# Predictive input/type-ahead for email address input, based on user's contacts?

Tags: android, user-controls, user-input, addressbook, type-ahead

In Android Google Mail app, when you start typing into the "To:" field in a new email, you will get a dropdown menu, auto-populated from your contacts.

I want this behavior in my app.

Currently, when my users enter an email address, they have to type the whole thing (into, essentially, an "textEmailAddress" input field). I want to make things easier by providing contacts-based predictive entry, Google-Mail-style.

How do I do this?

(So far, I have 1. googled, 2. looked through Android SDK documentation, 3. looked through Android sources (http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 things to do

1) Get All Contact's Email ID [See this Blog](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e44fa66e1849c1b/f2bd7a6edfe5e68f) and Also can Search for more exapmles
   After getting the Email IDs Store them in An `Array` say `emailArray`

2) Use the emailArray to show in an **[AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)**

Comment: This is the easiest way: follow the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html and just replace the contents of the ArrayAdapter with the email addresses you get from the contacts provider. It might be a bit slow (depending on how many email addresses the user has) but would work. Once you have that working you can look into using a SimpleCursorAdapter tied to the Contacts provider interface, but that's more complex and probably not the easiest way to start.